# Home User's Permissions Denied

Tags: server, permissions, 20.04, home-directory, user-management

I have 2 users on my server: `root` and`myuser`.

I am not exactly sure how, but I messed up `myuser`'s permissions while trying to edit my `home` directory as `root`. Now whenever I start up my server, `myuser` is denied permission to the `home` directory completely. The errors I get are `Could not chdir to home directory /home/myuser: Permission denied` and `-bash: /home/myuser/.bash_profile: Permission denied`. Also all the files are white instead of blue and green (and white). I used the `root` to look at the permissions of the `home` and `myuser` directories, but it shows that `myuser` is still the owner of both :

```
myuser@myserver:/bin$ sudo ls -l /home/
total 4
drw------- 22 myuser myuser 4096 Jun  8 18:13 myuser
myuser@myserver:/bin$ sudo ls -l /home/myuser/
total 44
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 May 28 19:46 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 May 28 19:46 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 May 28 19:46 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 May 28 19:46 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 May 28 19:46 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 May 28 19:46 Public
drwxrwxr-x 3 myuser myuser 4096 Jun  2 22:56 PythonScripts
drwxrwxrwx 2 myuser myuser 4096 Jun  2 22:30 sharefolder
drwxr-xr-x 4 myuser myuser 4096 Jun  7 03:51 snap
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 May 28 19:46 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 May 28 19:46 Videos
```

Is there a way to get `myuser`'s permissions back? Or is it a different problem?

Answer (score 3):

You need to, at least, change the permissions for /home/myuser:

```
   $ sudo chown myuser:myuser /home/myuser
   $ sudo chmod 755 /home/myuser
```

And see if that fixes it. It's hard to know what you did and how to completely undo it, but that should help.